# Calculate difference between two dates with timestamps in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, date, timestamp

I have in my table a timestamps with created_at and updated_at

```
$table->timestamps();
```

But I want to add another column that calculates the difference between created_at and updated_at in days

Should I do that in SQL or in my controller?

Comment: Have you used carbon facades??

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya No i didn't use

Comment: Can you try below answer code??

Comment: @OthmanBoūlal what should be the output, is it, in minutes, hours, or day, etc. ?

Comment: @gecko In hours, and if it is more than 24 hours, then in days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that from within your Eloquent model.
Let's assume your model has the name `User`.
You can create a computed field by defining an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

```
class User extends Model 
{
  $dates = [
    'updated_at',
    'created_at'
  ];
  $appends = ['diffInDays'];

  public function getDiffInDaysAttribute()
  {
    if (!empty($this->created_at) && !empty($this->updated_at)) {
      return $this->updated_at->diffInDays($this->created_at);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Some explanation

By adding `created_at` and `updated_at` to the `$dates` array, Laravel automatically casts your date values to [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).
Now, if you do something like `$user->created_at`, you don't get the string, but a Carbon instance of that date. This allows you to make some nice date calculations, like the one above.

By adding an Accessor with the `getDiffInDaysAttribute` function, you can call the days difference via `$user->diffInDays` like a normal attribute, although it is not on the model.

But if you would now do something like `$user->toArray()`, the `diffInDays` attribute will not be available.
To always add the difference in days when you retrieve User data, you can add the field to the `$appends` array.
That way, the field will always be returned when you retrieve User data via Eloquent.

Comment: It works, it calculates the difference, but I think it is calculated incorrectly because, for example, the difference between November 1 and November 21 is 20 days, but my table says 18

Answer (score 0):

Use `Carbon` for count date difference in days.

```
   $to = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $created_at);
   $from = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $updated_at);
   $diff_in_days = $to->diffInDays($from);
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it auto save this value on every update to that model, then you can put this in the model.

```php
public static function boot() 
{
    parent::boot();

    static::updating(function($model) {
        $diffInDays = $model->updated_at->diffInDays($model->created_at);
        $model->timestamp_difference = $diffInDays;
    });
}
```

`timestamp_difference` is the name of the DB column that I used, this can be whatever you want it to be.