# Difference between two days laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

Are there any way to get difference of two days (today & created_at) using laravel query?

I have tried as follows.but that didn't work for me

```
public function scopeActivatedOrders($query,$currentDate){
        return $query->select('*')
            ->where('orders.activated', '=', '1')
            ->where('DATEDIFF(order.arrived_date,$currentDate)','>','14')->get();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate difference between two dates with timestamps in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957324/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-with-timestamps-in-laravel)

Comment: I want to get the difference of two days using query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem in your code is that you are using standard where that take a column as the first parameter not an expression ...
you can use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw), or just using DB::raw like:

```
return $query->select('*')
            ->where('orders.activated', '=', '1')
            ->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(order.arrived_date,Now())>14')->get();
```

**note**: you can mysql [now()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-now-function.php) function instead of $currentDate variable ...

Answer (score 0):

try this  1st select then add in where condition

```php
public function scopeActivatedOrders($query, $currentDate)
    {
        return $query->select('orders.*', \DB::raw('DATEDIFF(order.arrived_date, NOW()) as diffday'))
            ->where('orders.activated', '=', '1')
            ->get()
            ->where('diffday', '>', '14');
    }
```

Comment: It gaving this error , SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'diffday' in 'where clause'

Comment: try now... i added that where condition after get so `diffday` will be available there

Comment: it is not showing any error, but when I dd() the result of that method in foreach it is not showing any data and it is not empty as well